# Trying to make a mod-10 counter with JK flip-flops in CircuitMaker but my outputs are always coming out HIGH instead of counting, not sure whats wrong

Tags: simulation, flipflop, counter, circuitmaker

Trying to make a mod-10 counter with JK flip-flops in CircuitMaker but my outputs are always coming out HIGH instead of counting, not sure whats wrong
[image]

Comment: Are the set and reset inputs active high or active low?

Comment: The reset state of each flop is indeterministic. You need to incorporate an external reset for deterministic start-up.